# push and setRoot to one page in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am getting below error when setting `Rootpage` in `ionic 3`.

> ```
>  Error: No component factory found for LoginPage. Did you add it to 
>  @NgModule.entryComponents?
> ```

but when I add this page into `aap.module.ts` in declaration and `entrypoint` section, this error is gone for `setRoot` but not for `push`. When I push, it is not working.

I guess that means I can do either `setRoot` or `push` to a one page in `ionic 3`?

[image: error image]

Comment: you can do both push and setroot

Comment: can you please upload your app.module.ts file>?

Comment: https://uploadfiles.io/0eo9q
see my aap.module.ts file